# How to get href from the entire page with scrapy (proper css selector)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape a real-estate website: https://www.nepremicnine.net/oglasi-prodaja/slovenija/hisa/. I would like to get the href that is hidden in the tag of the house images:

[image]

I would like to get this for the whole page (and other pages). Here is the code I wrote that returns nothing (e.g. empty dictionary):

```
import scrapy
from ..items import RealEstateSloItem
import time

# first get all the URLs that have more info on the houses
# next crawl those URLs to get the desired information

class RealestateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # allowed_domains = ['nepremicnine.net']
    name = 'realestate'
    page_number = 2
    # page 1 url
    start_urls = ['https://www.nepremicnine.net/oglasi-prodaja/slovenija/hisa/1/']

    def parse(self, response):

        items = RealEstateSloItem()  # create it from items class --> need to store it down

        all_links = response.css('a.slika a::attr(href)').extract()

        items['house_links'] = all_links

        yield items

        next_page = 'https://www.nepremicnine.net/oglasi-prodaja/slovenija/hisa/' + str(RealestateSpider.page_number) +  '/'
        #print(next_page)

        # if next_page is not None: # for buttons
        if RealestateSpider.page_number < 180:  # then only make sure to go to the next page
            # if yes then increase it --> for paginations
            time.sleep(1)
            RealestateSpider.page_number += 1
            # parse automatically checks for response.follow if its there when its done with this page
            # this is a recursive function
            # follow next page and where should it after following
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)  # want it to go back to parse
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here with css selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is looking for an `a` element inside the `a.slika`. This should solve your issue:

```
all_links = response.css('a.slika ::attr(href)').extract()
```

Those will be relative urls, you can use `response.urljoin()` to build the absolute url using your response url as base domain.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you!! Could you please tell me how you would use urljoin() in the existing code? Would you need a for loop?

Comment: Yes, you would need a loop. I suggest as a list comprehension like: `[response.urljoin(url) for url in all_links ]`